# Hibernate: Persisting objects leading to a memory leak

Tags: hibernate, memory-leaks

I might have some design concept wrong. If I have a table with 10000 rows means I'll have 10000 Objects?

I ask because I got a leak, and using Jconsole and Eclipse MTA, the only problem it shows me is an ArrayList which seems to be filled with the Objects retrieved from Hibernate.

Should I just increase the heap size? or what I'm meant to be doing?

UPDATE: The table reflects a file system structure and the purpouse is to retrieve all the childs of a given root, so I start with 100 rows (root folders) and then search for childs and grandchilds...

Obviously I won't be working with all of them at the same time, would like something like "keep the current folder tree persisted and kill it when switch root"

Comment: Turn off caching in Hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the 10000 objects in memory at the same time, then increase your heap size. If you need all 10000, but not necessarily at the same time, rewrite your code to load and process them in batches. If you only need some of the objects, optimize some queries to only load what you need. If you want better help, give a better explanation of your requirements

Comment: awesome explanation, I updated my question. Yes I don't need the 10000 all the time, how I load them in batches?